# Sistema de pagos con Stripe

Tags: nodejs, angular, stripe

Estoy haciendo una pasarela de pago utilizando Stripe usando NodeJs y Angular pero a la hora de generar un charge me sale un error (ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined at TokenCallback.token [as fn] (cart.component.ts:330) at TokenCallback.trigger (checkout.js:3)) he estado depurando el codigo pero no se muy bien que es lo que falla cuando hago la consulta a stripe mediante curl si me hace el pago pero usando la documentacion de la api no me deja hacerlo.

Este es mi endponit de node:

```
const stripToken = req.body.stripToken;
  const amount = req.body.amount
  stripe.charges.create(
    {
      amount: amount,
      currency: 'eur',
      source: stripToken,
      description: 'My First Test Charge (created for API docs)',
    },
    function (err, charge) {
      console.log(charge)
      if (err) {
        res.send({
          success: false,
          message: 'ERrorr'
        });
      } else {
        res.send({
          success: true,
          message: 'Success'
        })
      }
    }
  );
```

y esto es lo que tengo en la parte de Angular:

```
    loadStripe() {
    if (!window.document.getElementById('stripe-script')) {
      var s = window.document.createElement("script");
      s.id = "stripe-script";
      s.type = "text/javascript";
      s.src = "https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js";
      window.document.body.appendChild(s);
    }
  }

  pay(amount) {
    var handler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: 'pk_test_51H9oTAATbeiMfoWZHrm3q0QCUtANPgu7FJ2x1CLcb5zCALiQ3yGdCq23LjRC4D6KGtzyDeeIUKu8hruQneZBBfHs00fbbXUCym',
      locale: 'auto',
      token: function (token: any) {
        var body = {
          'stripeToken': token.id,
          'amount': amount * 100
        };
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        });
        this.http
          .post('http://localhost:3000/secret',
            body, { headers: headers })
          .subscribe(data => {
          }, error => {
          });
        
      }
    });

    handler.open({
      name: 'Panes&Co Checkout',
      description: '',
      amount: amount * 100
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está al utilizar `this.http.post(...` . `this.http` no está definido, causando que el código arroje la excepción.

Lo puedes solucionar utilizando una flecha:

```
token: (token: any) => {
  // `this` seguirá referenciando el contexto de Angular
}
```

Puedes leer sobre las condiciones de `this` [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), pero en pocas palabras, al usar la flecha (arrow) el scope de `this` sigue siendo el original (Angular), permitiendo utilizar `this.http`.